# Distorted circle when using border radius in CSS

Tags: html, css

In my page I have a menu icon on top left corner, and it is wrapped inside a circle, SO I used CSS3 border radius.

But the circle is not that smooth and I am getting some distortion along the corner. Is there any way to make it smooth.

If the `height` and `width` increased, I am getting the circle shape without distortion.

```css
#container{
    width:400px;
  height:400px;
  background:#000;
  padding:100px;
  }
#circle{
    width:40px;
  height:40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border:1px solid white;
  }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I look at your demo, I'm not seeing any distortion (iPad Air, Safari, iOS 7).

Comment: +1 for using the code snippet feature.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot showing the distortion? Looks good to me (Chrome 37 on OSX mavericks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this
http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-get-smoother-rounded-corners/
and do lemme know if this helps

Comment: Even though the link may contain answer to the question, please try to add relevant part of it here, so that it will persist even if other site go down.